# How can I install Ubuntu on my Playstation 3?

Tags: installation, ps3, powerpc

I'd like to use the Cell processors in a PS3. Given the changes to PS3 firmware recently, what is the best way to get Ubuntu installed on a PS3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have upgraded your firmware since the removal of the 'Other OS' feature, then there is no official way to install Ubuntu (or any other Linux distribution) on your PS3.

There was an unofficial SDK released for the PS3, which would possibly allow you to reinstate the feature, but I'm unsure of any possible legal issues so I won't link to it here.

Answer (score 0):

Oh sorry for the outdated link,

How about this..?

http://gizmodo.com/5143547/how+to-install-ubuntu-on-your-ps3-for-vintage-gaming-emulation

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=316047

Comment: That HOWTO is old, and doesn't appear to match current PS3 firmwares (in which the “Other OS” options have been removed).